# Bulding first app in Adobe livecycle

Tags: livecycle, lcds, livecycle-designer

hi i just installed workbech and livecycle server.i have to create an app in livecycle.
when i goto file >New >Application

a dialog appears in which  have to fill

username,
password ,
Log onto

what should e the value of all these three field so that i will able to create an app on live cycle.
can any one please help .i am new to livecycle didn't create any app please help from where i will get these values!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe's LiveCycle workbench connects directly to a LiveCycle server and the application is saved and deployed on the LiveCycle server itself.

You will have to enter the username and password associated with the server you are connecting to. You will also have to specify the hostname/IP address of the server to allow Workbench to connect and authenticate your credentials against the server. More details can be found in the [Adobe help Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/WorkbenchHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb766bbee6128402890a9-8000.html).

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks,
Armaghan.

Comment: please reply to this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477663/alc-ttn-105-000-could-not-connect-to-bootstrap-servlet