# ALC-TTN-105-000 could not connect to bootstrap servlet

Tags: livecycle, lcds, livecycle-designer

hi i am trying to install livecycle server using Adobe LiveCycle Configuration Manager.in this i reached to a slide heading is LifeCycle ES3 Database initialization there is a button labeled as initializa and two text field in host text field i entered localhost and in port i entered 8080 and getting error
ALC-TTN-105-000 could not connect to bootstrap servlet.Port[Connection refused:connect] may be invalid .
i tried other ports also 8081 8085 9090 etc but still facing the same error .can any one please tell how to resolve this error??please help i am a beginner and i am very excited to create my first app please help how to proceed further and resolve this issue!!

Answer (score 1):

Im afraid you have to provide more information on this before your question can be answered.

1. Are you trying to install a turnkey, express or custom LiveCycle server in your environment ?
2. What are you using as your application server and the database ?
3. Are you running any other applications on port 8080  ?
4. Is your application server up and running when you are getting the error.

From the generic message in your post, it seems like either the application server is down or something is blocking the communication to the application server.

Please review and follow the installation documentation listed [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/InstallJBoss/livecycle_install_jboss.pdf). If you are already following it, please provide answers to the questions outlined above to shed some more light on this.

Thanks,

Armaghan.

Comment: this time server is up and running and i am using turnkey jboss server and mysql database please reply to this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500879/pdf-generator-configuration-for-live-cycle