# PDF generator configuration for live cycle

Tags: livecycle, lcds, livecycle-designer

i installed livecycle server using turnkey its running i am able to login in workbench and created my first app.but during installation i unchecked pdf generator .after this i again uninstall and install it this time there is a pdf generator configuration box with heading "Admin User credentials for native PDF conversions" if you are config.native pdf conversions using LiveCycle PDF generator on Windowsserver2008,u must provide the account for at least one localthen in Username,password and add user button.i fill form got "Error while adding user" . my server is by default in turnkey is Administrator and password is password so i fill it and get error that "Error while adding user".please tell what should be the username and password for creating a user in pdf generator config window??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need PDF Generator for your solution ? If you dont, then you should not configure it at all. If you do need it, you need to specify user accounts to allow file conversions by the LiveCycle server. You can configure upto 3 windows ( domain or local ) accounts to facilitate high volume of PDF conversions. Essentially, for each thread, the LiveCycle server will open up Acrobat via a Corba call and will convert a required file  to a PDF. 
In order for this to happen, you will need to configure the server and accounts correctly. The details on how to configure the user accounts can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/adminHelp/admin.htm?content=000159.html)

Also, you can find the PDF Generator configuration settings [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/adminHelp/admin.htm?content=000159.html)

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks,

Armaghan